# input form validation by array field

Tags: reactjs

i have 2 text field in reactjs forms.i have validate this input field if it  has empty strings and undefined value and shown in toast message.i got problem in validating individual input field value lets say, want to validate the name field value  should should gets greater than 5 characters  and emailfield with regex

**PERSON form**

```
 const validate_data = (fieldValues = values) => {

   let check_fields = [

            {
                name: "Name",
                msg:"please enter Name"

                 //value:"greater than 5 characters"

            },
            {
                name: "Email",
                msg:"please enter Email address"
            },
          
     
        ]
        for(let checks in check_fields){
         
            let _checks = check_fields[checks]
            if (fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === "" || undefined ) {
                toast.error(_checks["msg"])
                return false
            }         
        }
return true 
}

const {values,handleInputChange} = useForm(data,true,validate_data);

**input form
              name="name"
                label="productname"
                    value={values.name }
                        onChange={handleInputChange} 
                       
                    />

**useformcomponent**

export function useForm(initialFValues,validateOnChange = false, validate) 
{
const handleInputChange = e => 
{
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setValues({
        ...values,
        [name]: value
    })
    if (validateOnChange)
        validate({ [name]: value })
}
```

Comment: if you using useForm, you can add maxLength as pattern while using register.
you can read more about that in here:
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

Comment: _`"if (fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === "" || undefined ) { toast.error(_checks["msg"])}"`_  It looks like you already have code for doing that.  Is this not running?  What's the problem?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger want to validate name input field accepts >5 characters only otherswise show msg (>5 charac required)

Comment: Your code is already doing that, isn't it?  Look at the code that I'm citing.  What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger yes it works for empty string but it accepts less than 5 characters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure it requires at least 5 characters, update your config to have a `minlength:5` property...

```
{
    name: "Name",
    msg:"please enter Name",
    minlength: 5
},
```

And then update your validation to use the new config, by checking if a `minlength` is defined and then comparing the `length(input)` against this, with our condition being `(_checks['minlength'] && length(fieldValues[_checks["name"]]) < _checks['minlength'])`...

```
if (
    fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === "" ||
    fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === undefined ||
    (_checks['minlength'] && length(fieldValues[_checks["name"]]) < _checks['minlength'])) {
    toast.error(_checks["msg"]);
    return false;
}
```

**Addendum**: I fixed this... `if (fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === "" || undefined ) {` to .... `if (fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === "" || fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === undefined ) {`.  I think this was a typo.

Comment: i think above doesnot work for multiple number of inputs fields with their own length validation .

Comment: It should.  Read the logic: `(_checks['minlength'] &&`.  If minlength is set, THEN it checks it for length limits.  Leave it unset on other elements, in `checkelements`, if you don't want it to be checked for length.